# Target specific platform for custom framework in a Cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, frameworks, cordova-plugins, plugin.xml

I'm developing a Cordova plugin for Android that includes custom frameworks, and one of them is only compatible with cordova-android >= 4.0.0.

I know in the plugin.xml file we can target cordova-android specific versions, but that applies on the whole plugin for the platform.

Here is a short version of my `plugin.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" id="com.plugin.MyPlugin" version="1.0">
    <name>MyPlugin</name>

    <engines>
        <engine name="cordova-android" version=">=4.0.0" />
    </engines>

    <js-module src="www/MyPlugin.js" name="MyPlugin">
        <clobbers target="MyPlugin" />
    </js-module>

    <platform name="android">
        <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
            <feature name="MyPlugin">
                <param name="android-package" value="com.plugin.MyPlugin" />
            </feature>
        </config-file>

        <source-file src="src/android/MyPlugin.java" target-dir="src/com/plugin/MyPlugin" />

        <framework src="path/to/first-framework" custom="true" />
        <framework src="path/to/second-framework" custom="true" />
    </platform>
</plugin>
```

Here, framework called "first-framework" works only with cordova-android < 4.0.0, and "second-framework" works only with cordova-android >= 4.0.0.

Basically my goal is **to have only one plugin.xml** file that declares :

- if cordova-android is < 4.0.0 : use "first-framework"
- else if cordova-android is >= 4.0.0 : use "second-framework"

How could I do this ?

Thanks